# javascript / mysql doesn't return message in result object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i want to create mysql tables, if they are not already created in my mysql database. 
the code itself is working, but I want to output a message either if there was a new table created or already one present with the same name.

```
con.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + guild + " (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, userid INT, username CHAR(50), messages INT)", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err    
            console.log(result.message)
        })
```

but if I am printing result.message it is always empty, even though when I am creating the database in mysql myself i get a returned message similar to "0 row(s) affected" if it worked or otherwise "0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1050 Table 'test' already exists".

So my question is, is there any way to check if a table was succesfully created via the return object or another somewhat easy way which does not involve multiple sql-queries.

for clarification:

when printing result if there is no table "test" already present, it looks like this:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

when there is a table named "test" already present it looks like this:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 1,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

the attribute "warningCount" is not indicating, I can't differ the warning, it can also be caused by other warnings mysql is outputting, so checking on that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` has attributes that you can use to display the warnings:

```
console.log(result.affectedRows + " row(s) affected");
console.log(result.warningCount + " warning(s)");
console.log(result.message);
```

Comment: when creating the table "test" if it isn't present already, printing "result" looks like this:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

but if "test" is already in my database, "result" will look like this:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 1,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

Comment: but the change in warningCount can also be caused by other errors mysql is outputting... So I do not know how I can distinguish between an error message, that the table is already created and another error...